# Android Volley Post Request. How to setEntity?

Tags: android, http-post, content-type, android-volley

I use a HttpPost in my code, where I add the entity like this:

```
String bodyContent = ".......";
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(bodyContent);
httpost.setEntity(se);
```

Now I want to change HttpPost in the Volley Request.
How to set setEntity?
I do not understand how I can insert my string bodyContent.
Should I use another method?

```
    boolean contentType = true/false;  

    //new post request in to volley
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Error.Response", "OK");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", "KO");
                }
            }
        ) {
       //add body content-type
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            if (contentType) {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            } else {
                return "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            }
        }
        //add header
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError 
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("VLHASH", "464646");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "Alif");
            params.put("domain", "http://itsalif.info");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: Did you find decision to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override getBody() as well like you have overridden getBodyContentType in your StringRequest

### Sample Code

```
String body = "test body";

 @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return body.getBytes();
    }
```